# First attempt at uploading a URL returns Exception_OverUrlUploadLimits

Tags: python, api, imgur

This is the function inside a selfwritten wrapper that uploads a url, then returns the link. Usually it works, except for the error I'm asking this for.

```
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.access_token}'}
    try:
        r = requests.request("POST", upload_url, data=url, headers=headers)
        key = r.json()
        print(key)
        # print(f"\n-----\n{key['data']['link']}")
        print('upload sucessfull')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'could not fetch url - {e} ')
    imgurURL = key['data']['link']
    return imgurURL
```

However, sometimes I get this error on a URL:

```
{'data': {'error': {'code': 1026, 'message': 'Upload limit for given URL has been reached.', 'type': 'Exception_OverUrlUploadLimits', 'exception': []}
```

Yet that is the first time I've tried uploading the image at the URL. Does imgur limit amount of url uploads from spesific domains? could that be the reason?

Comment: The exception certainly sounds like there is such a limit. And the first hit when I search for it is [this imgur documentation page](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/210076663-Upload-Images), which says "PRO TIPS: There is an upload limit of 50 images per IP address per hour."

Comment: Good to know, but that is still WAY below my usage. At most 2-3 pictures over the span of 4-5 hours.

Comment: Are you sharing a public IP with other people behind the same NAT router (maybe on a work or school network, or a public connection)?

Comment: Nope, private IP at home. No other IP has been using imgur

Answer (score 0):

> At most 2-3 pictures over the span of 4-5 hours.

This message is issued when too many requests are made with URL of the same domain at the same time. Perhaps you need to make a small pause between requests.